# Answering questions and adding screenshots later

Tags: discussion, answers

I often check the site and see questions that I can answer while I am on the go on my mobile device.  But I (obviously) don't have blender on my tablet, so I can't add any screenshots.  Usually I forgo answering the question and by the time I have access to a computer I have forgotten about it.  Most of the time the question gets answered (which is fine) but sometimes not.

**So my question is this**, is it acceptable to answer a question without access to blender and post applicable screenshots later?  And if so, should I say something like “I will post a screenshot shortly, when I can” in the answer?

Comment: I've run into that situation a few times, I guess the thing to do is to keep the answer as clear and detailed as you can, something that the OP or other readers can actually use, and then clarify it with screen shots later if it's too confusing. Keep in mind that there is quite a few users that get discouraged by a first unclear or incomplete answer and never come back to recheck, or give feedback (let alone mark the answer as accepted).

Comment: @cegaton so would it be proper to say "I will add a screenshot shortly", or something to that effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can reasonably answer a question without images, then my all means answer away. Take [my answer to this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15837/2217), I felt it was clear enough with out images. However a user asked for pictures, so 2 days after answering I added them.

I would caution you to not answer a question that really should have a picture, and say "image coming soon". As stated in the comments, incomplete answers can do more harm then good.

If for instance, you explain a modeling process. Giving the keyboard shortcuts and process, images may not be needed to convey a clear meaning of the answer.
Gandalf frequently answers a question, then shortly (after he finishes recording a video of the process) will updates his answer with a gif.

Answer (score 2):

In accordance with David's [answer](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/481/12), as long as you provide a decent worded answer, this shouldn't be a problem. What you should avoid however is slapping a few lines together in order to be the first to answer (as I've seen several times). Not only does this deter others from possibly adding other answers but your finished answer later might not even be correct or sufficient. So I say, answer if and only if you can get your point across in words, images can come later.